# Reading handwriting of David L. Aldrich's Occupation in 1860 Census?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, palaeography

I am trying to figure out David L. Aldrich's occupation. By the 1860 Census and after, he is listed as a cotton manufacturer. I know that he was also involved with the Richmond Bank from 1856 on. But I can't figure out what his occupation was as a young man (28) in 1850.

Here's one image:

[image]

Here's a close-up:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tin Pedlar - that is, an itinerant trader of tin.

Comment: Thanks. That's more specific than I was expecting. I'm more used to the catch-all "merchant."